# Why the while loop on asyncio task's done() method break even though the condition logic is always true?

Tags: python, task, python-asyncio, coroutine, cancellation

I'm trying to understand this code:

```
async def delay(sec: int):
    print(f"delay() going to sleep for {sec}s")
    await asyncio.sleep(sec)
    print("delay() waked up")


async def main():
    task = asyncio.create_task(delay(5))

    seconds_elapsed = 0
    while not task.done():
        print(f"checking task finished... {task.done()}")
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        seconds_elapsed += 1
        if seconds_elapsed == 3:
            print(f"cancelled result: {task.cancel()}")
            print(f"task is done: {task.done()}")

    print("main() awaiting task")
    try:
        # await task
        pass
    except asyncio.CancelledError:
        print("task was cancelled")
    print("main() finished")


asyncio.run(main())
```

The logs:

```
checking task finished... False
delay() going to sleep for 5s
checking task finished... False
checking task finished... False
cancelled result: True
task is done: False
checking task finished... False
main() awaiting task
main() finished
```

After 3s has passed, the task was canceled and the `task.done()` is still false, so the `while` loop continues with line 15...  finally the while loop break at line 16 and print line 22.

Pls help me to explain why? I thought that the while loop should run forever because the `task.done()` will always be false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running this slightly modified version of your code:

```
import asyncio

async def delay(sec: int):
    print(f"delay() going to sleep for {sec}s")
    await asyncio.sleep(sec)
    print("delay() waked up")


async def main():
    task = asyncio.create_task(delay(5))

    seconds_elapsed = 0
    while not task.done():
        print(f"checking task finished... {task.done()}")
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        seconds_elapsed += 1
        if seconds_elapsed == 3:
            print(f"cancelled result: {task.cancel()}")
            print(f"task is done: {task.done()}")
        print(f"Check task again: {task.done()}")

    print("main() awaiting task")
    try:
        # await task
        pass
    except asyncio.CancelledError:
        print("task was cancelled")
    print("main() finished")


asyncio.run(main())
```

You may notice that the output is now

```
checking task finished... False
delay() going to sleep for 5s
Check task again: False
checking task finished... False
Check task again: False
checking task finished... False
cancelled result: True
task is done: False
Check task again: False
checking task finished... False
Check task again: True # Look here!!!
main() awaiting task
main() finished
```

This is because you are calling `task.cancel()` after 3 seconds. This call successfully cancels the `delay` call, but it takes a moment for the status of the task to be set to done. If you remove the call to `task.cancel()` the while loop will run for the full 5 second delay you set.

```
import asyncio

async def delay(sec: int):
    print(f"delay() going to sleep for {sec}s")
    await asyncio.sleep(sec)
    print("delay() waked up")


async def main():
    task = asyncio.create_task(delay(5))

    seconds_elapsed = 0
    while not task.done():
        print(f"checking task finished... {task.done()}")
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        seconds_elapsed += 1
        if seconds_elapsed == 3:
            print(f"task is done: {task.done()}")

    print("main() awaiting task")
    try:
        # await task
        pass
    except asyncio.CancelledError:
        print("task was cancelled")
    print("main() finished")


asyncio.run(main())
```

Output:

```
checking task finished... False
delay() going to sleep for 5s
checking task finished... False
checking task finished... False
task is done: False
checking task finished... False
checking task finished... False
delay() waked up
main() awaiting task
main() finished
```